# How to get the list of users with permissions in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

We are trying create a Report, that should include the Person’s Full Name, user's Email Address, Azure Subscription Name, Resource Group Name, and Azure Role.

using this script:

```
Get-AzResourceGroup | ForEach-Object {
   Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroupName | Where-Object { -not $_.Scope.Contains("managementGroups") -and $_.ObjectType -ne "ServicePrincipal" | Select-Object DisplayName } 
}
```

we tried get user list, but we are not get the user names and their permissions

How to proceed?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and provide more details about your project? What did you try so far?

Comment: Regarding the issue, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.resources.models.authorization.psroleassignment?view=azurerm-ps to know the outputs of the command ```Get-AzRoleAssignment```

Answer (score 0):

The above snippet provides output with the following properties, detailed as [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.resources.models.authorization.psroleassignment?view=azurerm-ps#properties) of the **PSRoleAssignment** Class:

```
RoleAssignmentId
Scope
DisplayName
SignInName
RoleDefinitionName
RoleDefinitionId
ObjectId
ObjectType
CanDelegate
```

where `DisplayName` maps to the user's Full Name, `SignInName` maps to his/her Email address, `Scope` contains the Azure Subscription ID, and `RoleDefinitionName` maps to the user's role.

If you want to customize the properties in the output, consider using a [PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=pscore-6.2.0). Check [this](https://9to5it.com/using-psobject-store-data-powershell/) article for reference.